# How to embed Microsoft Word or Adobe Reader in my application?

Tags: c#, winforms

The following is supposed to work, but doesn't – it opens the file in a separate window.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(filename, false);
```

Comment: This used to work back in the days when programs still supported OLE Embedding.  Those days are over.  Completely for Word, Reader does it inconsistently.  And buggily.

Comment: @HansPassant Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I try to stay clear from answers like that, tends to become a magnet for ticked-off programmers that blame me for their trouble.  Feel free to post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried that already. I wrote "See Hans Passant's comment above." But [Robert Harvey♦](http://stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) deleted it. :) But I understand your point. Thanks again for this (and other) answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that though this seems to have worked in the past, it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is AcroPDF COM component you can add as reference.. It has and a visual component if you want to show something inside you application